# Use milliseconds in variable Time with R

Tags: r, time

I have a character variable containing the time with the format `H:M:S.ms`
To use this variable I want to recode 0:31:00.0 as a time variable but keeping the milliseconds. I tried to do the following:

```
BEAdata$Time <- strptime(BEAdata$Time, format='%H:%M:%S.%OS1')
```

But than I end up with a variables only containing missing variables.

Does anyone know how to code this variable and keep the milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as "year-month" is not a date (for lack of a day),  "hour-min-ss.subsec" is not a datetime.

But if you are willing / able to prepend a date then the different datetime parsers can help you.  My favourite is the one I wrote to not require formats.  A quick demo:

```
> tstr <- "00:31:00.0"    # added leading zero
> fullstr <- paste("2017-10-17", tstr)
> anytime::anytime(fullstr)
[1] "2017-10-17 00:31:00 CDT"
> 
> tstr <- "00:31:00.012345"    
> fullstr <- paste("2017-10-17", tstr)
> anytime::anytime(fullstr)
[1] "2017-10-17 00:31:00.012345 CDT"
>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `options(digits.secs = n)`, as demonstrated in the documentation for `strptime`, such that you'd end up with

```
options(digits.secs = 1)

foo <- strptime('0:31:00.0', format='%H:%M:%S.%OS')

foo
```

Answer (score -1):

`%OSn` is output-specific. From `?strptime`:

> Specific to R is **%OSn**, which for **output** gives the seconds truncated to
>   0 <= n <= 6 decimal places (and if %OS is not followed by a digit, it
>   uses the setting of getOption("digits.secs"), or if that is unset, n =
>   0). Further, for strptime **%OS** will **input** seconds including fractional
>   seconds.

Use `%OS` for inputing milliseconds - you can do:

```
(x <- strptime("0:31:00.5", format='%H:%M:%OS'))
# [1] "2017-10-17 00:31:00 CEST"
```

and then

```
format(x, '%H:%M:%OS5')
# [1] "00:31:00.50000"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It gives me milliseconds, but the original values are not kept. This is what I do:

# Import the data 

> library(readxl)

> BEAdata <- read_excel("~/Documents/BEAdata.xlsx", 
    col_types = c("text", "text", "text", "text", "text"))

This data containes one column with Times values. One examples of those values is "0:31:00.3". This is a character variable. Now I want this to be a time value, and keep the milliseconds in this variable.

Comment: @ItK And what exactly is wrong with `(x <- strptime("0:31:00.3", format='%H:%M:%OS'))` and `format(x, '%H:%M:%OS5')`? `x` is a time value and it also contains the milliseconds, as `format` shows you...

Comment: It doesn't keep the existing values of the variables in my dataset. It does contain milliseconds now, but it gives me the value zero instead of keeping the values in the existing dataset.